# orientDB `OrientGraphNoTx ` Super-class V; not exists

Tags: orientdb, tinkerpop-blueprint

I'm programmatically loading a file containing the OSql statements to create the schema of my DB by using the Blueprint API, specifically, I'm creating a DB in `plocal` mode by using by instantiating the `OrientGraphNoTx` class:

```
val graph = new OrientGraphNoTx(s"plocal:$dbPath", "admin", "admin")
```

I'm getting a weird error stating that the class `V` does not exist in my database:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandSQLParsingException: Error on parsing command at position #29: Super-class V; not exists
Command: CREATE CLASS Employee EXTENDS V;
```

Here is some sample code generating the error:

```
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val graph = new OrientGraphNoTx(s"plocal:C:\\Users\\alberto\\tmp\\tmp\\test_orient", "admin", "admin")
    val cmd = "CREATE CLASS Employee EXTENDS V;"
    graph.command(new OCommandSQL(cmd)).execute()
    graph.shutdown(true)
  }
```

As I have seen that few other people had a similar problem and solved it by specifying the keyword `graph` to their `CREATE DATABASE` statements, however, I guess the system should already know I'm working with a graph since I'm using `OrientGraphNoTx`.
I've tried anyway to add a `CREATE DATABASE` statement to my script but, as expected I got an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.orientechnologies.orient.core.command.OCommandExecutorNotFoundException: Cannot find a command executor for the command request: sql.CREATE DATABASE plocal:C:\Users\alberto\tmp\tmp\synth_1000 admin admin plocal graph
```

I'm using the jars included in the `lib` directory of OrientDB 2.1.4.

Does anybody know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you post all your code ?

Comment: Hi @AlessandroRota, I've edited the question adding come code generating the error and the OrientDB version I'm using. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Remove `;` so it's: `CREATE CLASS Employee EXTENDS V`

2) `CREATE DATABASE` is not a SQL command, but rather a console command

Comment: point 1) made it work! thanks! About point 2) do you know if there is a special class I should use instead of `OCommandSQL`?

Comment: oh, sorry, you were referring to `create database`, not `create class`. You can ignore my question :)